# HashSets and Execution of IEnumerables

Tags: c#

Does a HashSet always execute an unexecuted ienumerable when the HashSet needed?

For example:

```
list = new List { 1 ..... 1000);

var linq = list.Where(x => x > 10);

var hashSet = new HashSet(linq);
```

Now when I call `hashSet.Contains(7)` in a `for loop` will the `hashSet` always execute the Where statement when needed?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ..)
{
  hashSet.Contains(7);
}
```

Comment: No, it won't. `HashSet` does the job once in the constructor, and then keeps the result.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: That's an answer, not a comment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [`HashSet<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs) constructor

```
// this is the constructor you are using
public HashSet(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : this(collection, EqualityComparer<T>.Default) { }

public HashSet(IEnumerable<T> collection, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
        : this(comparer) {
        ...
        // removed unnecessary parts...
         this.UnionWith(collection);
       ...
    }
```

It calls `UnionWith` method with the given `IEnumerable<T>` which iterates over the items and add them if they are not already present

```
public void UnionWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
{
    ...
    foreach (T item in other) 
    {
         AddIfNotPresent(item);
    }
}
```

So the query is executed only once.

Answer (score 5):

No, the query is executed only when building your `HashSet` from an `IEnumerable<T>` (the constructor *enumerates* it to populate the set), so it won't be executed after.

Comment: Interestingly what it actually does is the constructor calls the public `UnionWith` method passing in the enunmerable (having set the set's capacity first if available).